# Can you kindof hide a transaction from the government if you use ATM?

Tags: taxes, money-transfer, atm, swift

I'm a citizen of NL. I keep my money in US.

1. I can send money from my US account to my NL account using Wise
2. I can withdraw cash from US via ATM. Then deposit the cash into my NL account via ATM while I'm in NL.

Is there any difference for tax purposes?

I hear something like if you regularly receive money, government might bother you and ask what you're doing with the assumption that you owe them taxes. Then you deal with red tape and you're guilty until proven otherwise.

When I send myself money with Wise, sender name on my statement is not me. Its Wise. So it looks like payment from a company, not a transfer between my own accounts. So I worry that it might cause me unnecessary work. And swift fees are too high

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any difference for tax purposes?

No.

Cash transactions, however, are more likely to raise red flags due to money laundering and illicit actions' funding concerns from the governments.